# Removing Duplicates in Javascript 2D Array

Tags: javascript

I have already first column sorted 2D Javascript Array

```
var arr = [[12.485019620906078, 236.90974767017053|166.7059999999991|244.15878139435978|156.54100000000025], 
[12.735148445872, 238.038907254076|203.3000000000006|245.7107245706185|213.46500000000034], 
[47.15778769718685, 238.038907254076|203.3000000000006|244.15878139435978|156.54100000000025], 
[47.580051233708595, 236.90974767017053|166.7059999999991|245.7107245706185|213.46500000000034]
];
```

I am trying to remove the duplicates based on the last two values in the [i][1] part of array

```
244.15878139435978|156.54100000000025
245.7107245706185|213.46500000000034
```

using following function which is not giving correct output

```
function remDupes(arr)
{
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
    {
        var i1 = arr[i][1].split("|");

        var item1 = i1[2]+"|"+i1[3];

        for(var j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
        {
            var i2 = arr[j][1].split("|");

            var item2 = i2[2]+"|"+i2[3];
            if(item1 == item2)
            {
                arr.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
    }
return arr;
}
```

I am looking for final array like this.

```
[
[12.485019620906078, 236.90974767017053|166.7059999999991|244.15878139435978|156.54100000000025], 
[12.735148445872, 238.038907254076|203.3000000000006|245.7107245706185|213.46500000000034]
]
```

Comment: You only have one value in the second index of each array. The bitwise OR `|` operator is going to return a single value.

Comment: Hope you are storing the value as string, not number. like this [12.485019620906078, "236.90974767017053|166.7059999999991|244.15878139435978|156.54100000000025"]

Comment: why dont you use a simple easy to remember values like 1,2,3 in your question for quick grabbing of your problems?